# Dired: Open files by external application in Linux

Tags: dired, linux

I want to open several types of files in Dired by different external applications.
For example:

- `.doc` files with LibreOffice
- `.pdf` files with evince
- `.jpg` files with pinta
- etc...

How do i configure this?

Answer (score 6):

Use Dired-x (standard library `dired-x.el`: put `(require 'dired-x)` in your init file).

Customize option **`dired-guess-shell-alist-user`**.  `C-h v` tells you:

> **`dired-guess-shell-alist-user`** is a variable defined in `dired-x.el`.
>
> Its value is `nil`
>
> Documentation:
>
> User-defined alist of rules for suggested commands.
>
> These rules take precedence over the predefined rules in the variable
>   `dired-guess-shell-alist-default` (to which they are prepended).
>
> Each element of this list looks like
>
> ```
> (REGEXP COMMAND...)
> ```
>
> where each `COMMAND` can either be a string or a Lisp expression that evaluates
>   to a string.
>
> If this expression needs to consult the name of the file for
>   which the shell commands are being requested, it can access that file name
>   as the variable `file`.
>
> If several `COMMAND`s are given, the first one will be the default
>   and the rest will be added temporarily to the history and can be retrieved
>   with `M-x previous-history-element` (`M-p`) .
>
> The variable `dired-guess-shell-case-fold-search` controls whether
>   `REGEXP` is matched case-sensitively.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Then just use `!` or `&` on files in Dired. Use `M-n` to retrieve the default value of the program to run, which will come from your entries in the option value.

Answer (score 3):

Using **&** from dired prompts to open each file with an external application.
Searching and trying, these *elisp* lines made it work:

```
  (setq dired-guess-shell-alist-user '(("\\.pdf\\'" "evince")
                                   ("\\.doc\\'" "libreoffice")
                                   ("\\.docx\\'" "libreoffice")
                                   ("\\.ppt\\'" "libreoffice")
                                   ("\\.pptx\\'" "libreoffice")
                                   ("\\.xls\\'" "libreoffice")
                                   ("\\.xlsx\\'" "libreoffice")
                                   ("\\.jpg\\'" "pinta")
                                   ("\\.png\\'" "pinta")
                                   ("\\.java\\'" "idea")))
```

Comment: Each `setq` you perform this way changes the value of the variable, so I doubt this works.  You can check the final value with `C-h v dired-guess-shell-alist-user`.

Comment: @JeanPierre Yes, you are right. Newbie error. I just corrected it with some values I am currently using. Tested it using use-package.

Answer (score 3):

In 2022, and emacs 28.1, all you have to do is

- navigate to dired file in dired
- press `W`

Which runs `(browse-url-of-dired-file)` and seems to open the file or directory in the default application.